# Multi-Catch throwing compilation error. Individually, it is working fine

Tags: java, multi-catch

I am using a JDK 1.8 and I am facing a compilation problem something like below, when using multicatch.

**Multiple markets in this line: Syntax error in token "|",. expected
FileNotFoundException.IOException cannot be resolved to a type.**

I checked a few related threads for multicatch but could not find the reason why I am facing this problem.

```
try
{
        try
        {
           //LOGIC
        } 
       finally
       {
       }
}catch ( FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
           //EXCEPTION HANDLING                     
        }
```

PFA the screen grab to show the JDK version configured and the multi-catch throwing the exception.

[image]

@Tunaki - With individual catch statements it is working fine. I don't think it is because the finally block is before the catch block- PFB the screengrab:

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with the use of the multi-catch. The syntax of the try-catch-finally is just incorrect. See the linked question.

Comment: on a Sidenode, your IDE will probably tell you that the `IOException` already includes the catch of the `FileNotFoundException`, as `FileNotFoundException` inherits from `IOException` and wont compile the code.

Comment: The `catch` block should be **before** finally

Comment: @Piotr  - When I don't user multi-catch, it is working fine.

Comment: @Piotr - I have uploaded a screengrab without multi-catch

Comment: Please use formatter. I cant read your code because of lack of indentation.

Comment: @wisemann I have shown a screengrab for showing the exception alone. I have re-written the code block, so my question is understandable.

Comment: @Tunaki - I don't think this is a duplicate. Pls check once again and mark accordingly.

Comment: Yes this is not a duplication of that question. @Gnz Types in multi-catch must be disjoint. Because these exceptions are subclass of the other. You can not join them. This is a logical mistake. Option 1: disjoint them, option 2: remove FileNotFoundException.(IOException is superior then FNFEx)

Comment: This wasn't clear at all with the initial revision, but please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345287/not-able-to-use-multi-catch-from-java-effectively for the explanation of this. There is no need to reopen this.

Comment: @wisemann , [at]kevin-esche [at]Tunaki  Thanks - I understand that subclassed exceptions could not be multi-catched. But shouldn't the compilation error thrown should be stating that? Instead, I am getting something else... Can you clarify on that if possible?